# appending data before an element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm developing a wall and I'm having trouble with the following code. As you can tell from the image below that new comments are added to the bottom. But I need it to be appended but appended before the commentBox. I thought maybe the .before() would come in handy but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

[image]

jQuery:

```
e.closest('.status-border-bottom-box1').find('.commentsList').append(html); // needs to insert before commentBox
```

Html:

```
        <div class="commentsList" style="width: 104%">
        <div id="commentLikeListing" style="width: 100%; display: none"></div>
<?php   $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM wallpostcomments wp INNER JOIN users u ON u.userid = wp.userid WHERE wallPostId = '{$row->idwallPosts}' ORDER BY wp.idwallPostComments ASC");
        foreach($query1->result() as $row1)
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { ?>
        <div id="likeList" style="display: none; width: 95%"></div>
        <div id="commentsList" style="width: 96%">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 408px" class="style1 commentStyle">
        <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 10px">
        <img style="padding: 3px" id="defaultImg a0" src="<?=base_url().$row1->defaultImgURI?>" align="left" width="25px" height="25px" />
        &nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top" style="width: 319px">
        <a class="font1 link-font1"><b><?=$row1->firstname.' '.$row1->lastname?> </b></a><?=$row1->entryData.'<br>'.date('m/d/Y h:ia ', strtotime($row1->DateTimeCreated))?></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <input placeholder="Write a comment..." id="commentBox-<?php echo $row->idwallPosts; ?>" class="textbox1" style="width: 400px"></input>
        </td>
        </tr>

</table>
<?php } } else { ?>
    <div id="commentsListNewData" class="commentStyle" style="visibility: hidden; width: 96%"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="font2" style="text-align: center">Sorry but you are not associated with any churches. Click <span class="link-font1" id="findChurch">here</span> to find your church.</div>
    <?php } ?>
        <div id="newData"></div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: Do you mean `.parent().append(html);`? - that markup with all the embedded PHP is hard to read, would be better to see the rendered markup here really.

Comment: You have everything inside a div with `class="commentsList"` and afterwards a div with `id="commentsList"`. That is confusing and you should change it. Maybe you are thinking of the second but jquery is finding the first?

Comment: Yeah I know the logic is kind of messed up. How should I set it up to work?

Comment: @Mark.. are you needing to see my webpage? and .parent().append(html); still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

prepend ? http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Its not exactly clear what you want, but jQuery is likely have the specific built in function for it. And as mentioned elsewhere you have two `commentsList`, which rings an alarm bell.

Comment: that adds it to the very beginning of the list though. I need it to append to the end of the list

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "comment box", jquery is pretty friendly  when it comes to placing an object in a specific place, have a look through their docs

Answer (score 0):

Try [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) function. It insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

```
e.closest('.status-border-bottom-box1').find('.commentsList').after(html);
```

Comment: it still doesn't work because .commentsList and .status-border-bottom-box1 are elements that extend all the way to the bottom of the post. so it will still add it to the bottom.